# How old is my kitten?

Tags: cats, age

I've found this kitten beside me when I was sleeping (I don't even know whose cat this is) and now I've decided to become part of the family, but I need to determine the age of the kitten. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to tell how old a kitten is just by looking at a photo.

However, we can estimate, and I would agree that 3-5 months is likely the right range.

The most reliable way to age kittens is to look at their teeth. All the baby teeth will be present by about 2 months. The baby teeth are smaller and sharper than the adult teeth. All the adult teeth erupt by about 6 months in most cases. There will be natural variation in timing, but this gives an idea. This is a useful chart for determining kitten age by dentition (click to enlarge):

[image]

Weight and body condition can also be considered in aging a kitten, but we don't know if this kitten is male or female, spayed or neutered, underfed or adequate body condition. It's hard to tell whether this kitten looks rather thin simply because it is rapidly maturing or because it was malnourished. As a very rough figure I go by 1 lb per month of age, for example 4 lbs at 4 months, but there will be huge variation depending on the kitten.

If you are adopting this kitten, a vet will need to take a look, perform any necessary vaccinations, deworm, and spay or neuter when the time is right. They will be able to advise better on the age by fully examining the kitten.

Answer (score 1):

your cat is about 4 months old after what i can see but  this is an estimate so it can be two weeks younger or older.

i base this on body shape and on how developed the limbs are and the fact that the muscles are not yet fully developed.

so you have a little teen cat in your house,remember to get it to the vet for a health check and to get it vaccsinated and spayed/neutered.

you need to be sure it do not have an owner before you addopt it,some child might have lost their kitten so this is something you need to find out before you do anything.

Comment: I was thinking 12-15 weeks old.

Comment: And please follow up here so we know what is happening with your “new addition.”